# Why are my recessed IC lights overheating?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting, bulb

I was sitting in my new home with dimmable recessed incandescent lights when I noticed one light fixture "click" off and then 10 minutes later click back on. Then the fixture on the other side of the room did the same thing. I put my hand on the ceiling next to a fixture and sure enough it seems quite warm.

OK, so they're overheating... but why?

- One bulb is a 40W A19 bulb and the other looks like a 45W R20.
- The fixtures are Elite B4IC-AT-W with B401W/WH trim, which [the spec sheet](https://www.platt.com/CutSheets/Elite%20Lighting/ELI_B4IC_PDF.pdf) says "Accommodates up to 50W PAR20, R20, and A19 lamps."

Are they installed incorrectly? Should I just replace them all with LED (or CFL) bulbs and not worry about it?

Comment: I'd also appreciate any advice on replacement bulbs. I've heard good things about the Cree Soft White bulbs, but I've only seen them in A19 and I like the shape of R20 better.

Answer (score 1):

The light is designed to dissipate heat through the top of the housing. If you have the ability check to make sure the top of the housing is able to get airflow.

CFL and LED lights will help your situation as they do not produce as much heat.